# on page load event Fetch data is not working In React

Tags: reactjs

First time when my page loaded then my app total lost page.
but when I comments my array /*ClientsList.map(item => so on */ which is displaying data then page loaded. then I uncomments my array then data displayed successfully and app run.
Again If I refresh my page then app lost.

```
 const [ClientsList, setUsersList] = useState({}); 

  React.useEffect(() => {
       
        let BaseURL = 'https://******.com/taxplanner/rest-apis/users/clientslist';
              
            fetch(BaseURL, {
                method: 'POST',
                data: {id:loggedIn}
                })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((res) => {
                
                 setUsersList(res.clients);
                   
                      })
                .catch((error) => {
                 console.log(error);
                
              });

      }, [""]);

    return (
       <>
         
             <List type="unstyled" className="p-0 text-left bg-white">
                {
                    /* when I comments my following array*/

                              ClientsList.map(item =>
                          
                              <li className="my-2">
                                <a
                                  className="allFormTitle"
                                  
                                  href="#pablo"
                                  onClick={(e) => {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    setSingleClient(item);
                                  }}
                                >
                                  {item.first_name +' '+ item.last_name}
                                </a>
                              </li>
                            )
                      }
              </List>
          </>
         )
```

My Array Object is like this

---

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Mohammad",
    "last_name": "Shafique",
    "project_title": "attarisoft@gmail.com",
    "business_name": "Attarisoft",
    "street_address": "*****",
    "city": "Faisalabad",
    "state": "Alaska",
    "zip": "48000",
    "phone": "+923238383992",
    "dependents": 25,
    "registration_date": "2022-09-28 15:23:28",
    "status": 1
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Mohammad",
    "last_name": "Ateeq Raza",
    "project_title": "*****@gmail.com",
    "business_name": "Abuateeq",
    "street_address": "*****",
    "city": "Faisalabad",
    "state": "Alabama",
    "zip": "48000",
    "phone": "+923238383992",
    "dependents": 25,
    "registration_date": "2022-09-28 15:23:28",
    "status": 1
},

]
```

////////////////////////////////////////
I am trying a lot but not resolved my issue . please help to resolve my problem with thanks
Regards

Comment: change `[""]` to `[]`

Comment: are you trying  to **get** data or **post** it to the server

Comment: Change  `const [ClientsList, setUsersList] = useState({});`  to  `const [ClientsList, setUsersList] = useState([]);`

Comment: yes Resolved to change as per your directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your initial value of the ClinetsList state. the inital value is an empty object but you're trying to execute .map function on it.

So your app will crash. In order to fix it, change the initial value to an empty array:

```js
const [ClientsList, setUsersList] = useState([]);
```

There is another problem in your useEffect dependency. It should be an empty array ([]) and not ([""]) in order to be executed only 1 time:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
       
  let BaseURL = 'https://******.com/taxplanner/rest-apis/users/clientslist';
              
  fetch(BaseURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    data: {id:loggedIn}
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((res) => {
    setUsersList(res.clients);                
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}, []);
```

And also it's better to have same names for your state and setState function like this:

```js
const [usersList, setUsersList] = useState([]);
```

Comment: Thanks dear. @Amirhossein please like my question so that my reputation will increase and I will be able to like Answers to other people

Comment: Sure. Please also choose my answer as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: yes sure I choose but me needs more reputations to choose as a correct answer.

Comment: I don't mean voting, you have an option to pick the correct answer without any reputations needed: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. But thanks anyway for your voting.

Comment: This problem again faced in SingleClient Page usering
 const [singleClient, setSingleClient] = useState([]);
and in Fetch function
 let BaseURL = 'https://mentorlogix.com/taxplanner/rest-apis/users/clientslist?id'+clientId;
           can you help this one please

Comment: Sure. Could you add your code ?

Comment: 'const Id = window.location.href.split('/')[5];
  const [Client, setClient] = useState([]);
           useEffect(() => {
           
            let BaseURL = 'url/c?id='+Id;
                 fetch(BaseURL, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {id:id}
                    })
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((res) => {
                        setClient(res.clients);
                       
                          })
                 
                  });
  
          }, []);
    '

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249902/discussion-between-muhammad-shafique-attari-and-amirhossein).

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this one to change this

```
   const [ClientsList, setUsersList] = useState({}); 

     ///To////

   const [ClientsList, setUsersList] = useState([]);
```

This direction given by

https://stackoverflow.com/users/17565505/script0
thanks a lot